# Global floating bar for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to make an application which when started will remain as a floating icon on top of other application windows and can be maximized when clicked on that icon. It will help the users to access the application easily.

Comment: It will not make anything easy for the users, they would hate your app. Luckily, this is not possible. To launch an app, or "maximize" it as you call it, they go to start and tap the tile. That is easy and works for all applications alike. Now, if this is an enterprise app, not a store app, I believe there are other options starting with Windows Phone 8.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in Windows Phone. The reason being each and every application has its own UI Layer defined and this UI Layer cannot overlap system windows or any other application's window.

Additionally, when you switch an application or press "Window" key on the phone, the currently running application is tombstoned. During this phase, application has only memory footprint and optionally processor footprint if its taking advantage of Background Processes. Considering this fact, its given that UI is not active at all for tombstoned application.

Due to above mentioned reasons, its not possible to have a floating icon on  top of other application windows.

Comment: Any option like adding to a global context menu?

Comment: There's not such thing as "global context menu" in WP.

Comment: No. Windows Phone doesn't permit to do that. The only option is to use "Sharing" option / App to App sharing.